# How to install intel x86 fro android 4.4.2 (API 19)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

Newer of Xamarin on visual studio. i try to install android 4.4.2(API 19) but i cant see  intel x86 atom system in that folder. Can you tell, How to get it and How to solve this problem

I can't show the picture because my reputation < 10

Please help and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First install HAXM from SDK and then install intel x86 .
if HAXM is not installing then enable the virtualization from BIOS in WINDOWS.
I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Ok, Thank you for quick response. i want to try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can download HAXM from this site: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

For Windows 8.1 you need an another version, read the docs!